# How to redirect to a different url in webview if the cookie is expired?

Tags: android, cookies, webview

Whenever the login cookie is expired i have to check the loading URL is ending with some string, then i have to redirect it with another URL. How can i do that?

```
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
if (url.endsWith("admin/login")) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("cookies", null).apply();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                    //  Log.d(C.TAG, "Using clearCookies code for API >=" + String.valueOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1));
                    CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
                    CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
                } else {
                    //  Log.d(C.TAG, "Using clearCookies code for API <" + String.valueOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1));
                    CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(MainActivity.this);
                    cookieSyncMngr.startSync();
                    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                    cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
                    cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
                    cookieSyncMngr.stopSync();
                    cookieSyncMngr.sync();

                }
                view.clearHistory();
                view.clearCache(true);
                view.loadUrl(URL_BASIC);
            }  return true;
        }
```

In this case, the call comes repeatedly with the **admin/login** URL. It won't get loaded with the URL i provided.

Comment: Are you getting to the view.loadUrl() line? If so, I would suggest adding a flag that will only allow this piece of code to be launched once (and reset the flag when the loading is finished). If you are not getting to that line, you should give some more details

Comment: At first it comes to view,loadurl, then it loads with the URL which i'd given, then again comes inside shouldoverrideurloading, but with the url i given. Then it again comes with the **admin/login** so again view.loadurl get called.

Comment: So you might be getting into some loop - try what I suggested, to allow your loadUrl to only be called once. Tell me if you need further clarifications.